# R Table modification

Tags: r, plyr, data.table

How do I take the average of a few entries in a column whose corresponding entry in another column,has the same entries?

For instance I have a large table with say 3 columns, time and prices being 2. and lets say under the time column the values repeat. like 10:30 appears 4 times, then i would need to take the average of the corresponding price column entries and summarize the same onto a single row of 10:30 with a single price of it. Can someone provide me some insights?

Sample data:

```
time      prices     size
10:00        23        1
10:15        12        3
10:30        12        1
10:30        19        4
10:45        12        1
```

I would like to modify rows 3 and 4 merging into a single row, averaging the prices.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
tapply(prices, time, mean)
```

For a more complete picture, see `?tapply`

But what would you like to do with the column `size`?

**EDIT:**

To take the mean of prices and the last value of size, here's one suggestion:

```
myDF<-data.frame(time=c("10:00","10:15","10:30","10:30","10:45"),
  prices=c(23,12,12,19,12),size=c(1,3,1,4,1))

theRows <- tapply(seq_len(nrow(myDF)), myDF$time, function(x) {
  return(data.frame(time = head(myDF[x, "time"],1), prices = mean(myDF[x, "prices"]),
    size = tail(myDF[x, "size"], 1)))
  }
)

Reduce(function(...) rbind(..., deparse.level = FALSE), theRows)
```

p.s. This can be done very well using `ddply` -- see Paul's answer, too!

Comment: Thanks thats very helpful, for the size column , I would like it to consider the last entry .. I would like it to retain 4 in this case. and thats how it must work for all.

Answer (score 3):

You could also take a look at the `plyr` package. I would use `ddply` for this:

```
ddply(df, .(time), summarise, 
   mean_price = mean(prices),
   sum_size = sum(size))
```

this assumes your data is in `df`. For a more elaborate description of `plyr`, please take a look at [this paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01) in the Journal of Statistical Software.

Other alternatives include using `data.table`, or `ave`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I do not quite follow the functionality of ddply. what if i would like to add up the contents of the size column , average out the prices column for entries that have the same time at various rows.

Comment: I extended my code to include summing of the size column, in addition I added a reference to a paper which describes plyr quite nicely.

Comment: Although I have a question on how do i retain the value of the time column at the same time. when i run the above command, it re writes the entire column labeling the columns as "1,2,3..", but I want the previous value to be retained

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example as an additional section to your question?